# Please help me in php mysq to count data by group

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table clicks like this

```
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
|  id |   time   |   site   |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
|  1  | 8 4 2013 |   site1  |
|  2  | 8 4 2013 |   site1  |
|  3  | 9 4 2013 |   site2  | 
|  4  | 6 4 2013 |   site1  |
+-----+-----+------+--------+
```

I want to show result like this

```
   Date      |       Count
  8 4 2013   |       2 click
  6 4 2013   |       1 click
```

i have this code

```
$id = 'site1';
$getclk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE site='$id'");
$clk = mysql_num_rows($getclk);
print $clk;
```

this code show only count of rows and i want to show count of row grouped by time.

GROUP BY command works for this but i don't know how to do this.

please help me i dont know how to do this, please give me full code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
SELECT COUNT (id) as countClicks, time as Date
FROM clicks
[WHERE site = ?]
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY countClicks DESC
```

Also, you shouldn't use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$getclk="SELECT date,count(*) as c FROM Clicks WHERE site='$id' GROUP BY date ORDER BY c DESC";
```

Then loop through the results and display them.  `please give me full code to do this.` So Sorry, not the right forum for that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT time, COUNT(*) as count FROM clicks GROUP BY time
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you result in the format you've asked for:

```
$getclk = mysql_query("select time as Date, concat(count(*), ' click') as Count 
                       from Clicks 
                       where site = '$id' 
                       group by time 
                       order by Count desc");
```

Please note the use of mysql function `concat()` function to append `click` text to number of records grouped by time under `Count` column would be better if you appended this text in php instead of mysql so that less data would be transferred from the database server.

As already made aware by other answerers, `mysql_` functions are deprecated, you should be using either `mysqli` or `pdo` for new code.

Answer (score 0):

write Your query like below

```
$id = 'site1';
$getclk = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) as clcount,time FROM clicks WHERE site='$id' group by time order by time");
$clk = mysql_num_rows($getclk);
print_r($clk);
```